# Opencart - custom options based on name and type

Tags: php, opencart

Do Opencart allow to add/execute custom options based on specific names?

For example: in the file `product.tpl` I added `&& ($option['name'] == 'Select Color')` to the default `image` option => `<?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') && ($option['name'] == 'Select Color') { ?>` => only to execute this option when the type will be `image` and the name will be `Select Color`

I need this to create custom styling options for my product.

Is this possible in Opencart?

Because I have tried this method and my product page went blank and reversed it to the default state without `&& ($option['name'] == 'Select Color')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition isn't correct.
Try this instead:

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'image' && $option['name'] == 'Select Color') { ?>
```

The braces were not set correctly.

Comment: Thank you Stefan! It is working, I do not knew that a `)` or `(` could have so much power in the syntax text.